# Teradata Auto-Increment Query

Tags: sql, teradata

Can Teradata SQL Query do Auto-Increment?

I'm looking for something similar to

```
SELECT
  Date (Auto-Increment by 1 over Column 2),
  Column 2,
  Column 3
FROM Fake_Table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

And get something such as

```
Date        Column 2    Column 3
2012-06-11  A           A
2012-06-11  A           B
2012-06-11  A           C
2012-06-12  B           A
2012-06-13  C           B
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the ROW_NUMBER() window aggregate with a PARTITION BY and ORDER BY statement to provide you a seed value to add to the DATE.

Pseudo-Code:

```
SELECT
  CURRENT_DATE + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column2,
                                   ORDER BY Column2)       AS MyDate
  Column2,
  Column3
FROM Fake_Table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: This does help, however, is there any way to force the increment to go up to a limit? Meaning: The date does increment all the way up to September, but I want to force it to go all the way to December.

Comment: What if you bring the SYS_CALENDAR.Calendar view into the query so that you can specify which 12 months of dates to work with.